# How to interpret this Mathematica command input as given in book?

Tags: real-analysis, mathematica

I am unable to understand what the book stands for by the given command shown as input in Mathematica, as given at its Googlebooks limk [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ij6LDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Exploring%20Calculus:%20Labs%20and%20Projects%20with%20Mathematica%20Crista%20Arangala%20Karen%20A.%20Yokley&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPvOiH-_XiAhUVU30KHeKfCcAQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=Exploring%20Calculus%3A%20Labs%20and%20Projects%20with%20Mathematica%20Crista%20Arangala%20Karen%20A.%20Yokley&f=false).

[image]

I mean the line given by:
$lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} cos2(2x)2x -3.$

I tried to look into Mathematica syntax for inputting, and found that subscripts, and superscripts are allowed; as is also allowed to show fractions directly in input.

So, how should I interpret the same:
as: $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} cos^{2(2x)}2x -3$, or not?

Comment: Is it Limit[Cos[2] (2 x) 2 x - 3, x -> Infinity] or Limit[Cos[2 (2 x) 2 x - 3], x -> Infinity] or Limit[Cos[(2 x)]^2 (2 x) - 3, x -> Infinity] or something else? How is one supposed to interpret that function definition - does the book give any clues on that?

Comment: @Moo The book till that lab. is fully given. But, why such a weird syntax is shown is not clear. Was such syntax in earlier versions?

Comment: Okay, I looked in the book, and an earlier part had that function defined as Limit[Cos[(2 x)]^2/(2 x - 3), x -> Infinity]. It looks like some of the copy was corrupted and not readable (the graphic). I added the Mathematica syntax around the function.

Comment: @Moo Please give a screenshot, as am unable to get that page. Also, how to interpret that. I hope it works as: $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\cos(2x)^{\frac{2}{2x-3}}.$

Comment: That is **not** it, please see the answer I added because I could not make it a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched in the book, Exploring Calculus: Labs and Projects with Mathematica Crista Arangala Karen A. Yokley,  for Lab-2, and here is what those functions were intending.

[image]

In Mathematica syntax, the last item $i$ is defined as (of course they want you to use the items listed and not this approach), so you can see how to input that function

```
  Limit[Cos[2 x]^2/(2 x - 3), x -> Infinity]
```

Here is a [*Google Books*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HsXBDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&dq=Exploring+Calculus:+Labs+and+Projects+with+Mathematica+Crista+Arangala+Karen+A.+Yokley,+lab+2&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil2YvrlvbiAhWXFjQIHdR-Cs8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Exploring%20Calculus%3A%20Labs%20and%20Projects%20with%20Mathematica%20Crista%20Arangala%20Karen%20A.%20Yokley%2C%20lab%202&f=false) link.

Comment: Please give webpage address, as my link for the book at googlebooks is not showing the same.

Comment: @jiten: I added a link to the book - just scroll down a bit. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, seemingly your link is the correct one.